# Reload Application Without Restarting Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to know how I can reload the entire application as if it first started without restarting Tomcat. I cannot seem to find an answer to what I'm looking for. Essentially, I would like to create a controller method that I can call that will cause the reloading of the application.

Comment: First make sure that `reloadable` is set to `true` in `context.xml`.  Then, you can run `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("touch [path to web.xml]")`.  This will force Tomcat to reload the application.

Comment: I'm not using any xml config, is there an example of how to do with it Java config? I also don't have a web.xml either, haven't run across a need for it yet. I'm still fairly new to Spring and have been following the guides and documentation on the spring.io site. If you can please point me to examples, documentation, etc... that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `context.xml` is a Tomcat configuration file not a Spring configuration file.  Even if you are using Java based configuration, just include a valid and otherwise empty `web.xml` in your application.

Comment: This is what OSGi is for

Answer (score 3):

Have you heard about JRebel plugin of eclipse.

https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [tomcat manager app](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Introduction)? You can deploy and undeploy apps without restarting.

Comment: I have a CMS that I'm working on and would like to make plugins loadable programmatically as part of the "installing" a plugin process.

Comment: What do you mean by "plugin"?